# why tkinter will resize the windows when I open the another pyqt5 windows?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt5

StackOverflow.
why the Tkinter windows will resize when I use Tkinter open another pyqt5 window?
here is my code:

```
tk.Button(self.frame, text="start", fg="white", bg="#708090",command=lambda: MyThread(self.test)).place(x=15,y=265,relwidth = 0.18,relheight=0.09)
def test(self):
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win_root = MainWindows()
win_root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I need to use pyqt5's Module like QtWebEngineWidgets, but I don't want to rewrite my program use pyqt5, so I try to use tk.Button to open the pyqt5 windows, it works, but I don't know why the Tkinter windows will resize its windows. The original size is 500x500, but it will be 300x300 when open pyqt5 windows.
Thanks!!!

Comment: You should *not* mix different frameworks in the same program. In any case, provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and be careful about the [code formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Both `tk` and `PyQt5` take control of the execution loop because their backends are not Python code but pre-compiled dynamic link libraries. In either case, the CPython interpreter transfers the control of execution to the dll, and you'll get a very undefined behavior when you mix `tk`, `PyQt5`, and, worse, `threading`.